# Rationale and need for rule barring low-reputation users from inserting images

Tags: discussion, reputation, images, privileges, new-users

Occasionally, a new user will ask a question for which a picture is required.  Sometimes it's because they don't have the time, energy, or knowledge to convert a handwritten or typeset equation (often their own substantial work) into MathJax/LaTeX, but sometimes it's because an actual diagram is vital to understanding the question.

Because they're new, the user will have insufficient reputation to insert the actual picture into the question.  They are forced to simply link to the picture (as, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873889/should-one-always-perform-logical-reasoning-intuitively-and-contentually)).  As a result, the question seems incomplete, it gets downvotes, etc.  Sometimes, it's warranted, but not always.  Someone often comes by to do the image insertion for them (or to convert into MathJax), but this seems like a kluge, making someone wait around for that.

I assume that the restriction for importing an image is for some reason such as resource consumption, but I've never seen this reason stated.  It might be somewhere in the site rules I haven't looked, but for example, searching "insert image reputation" here or on the main Math SE site didn't turn up anything.  Whatever the reason is, is it worth hamstringing new users in this way?  Perhaps a limit on image size could be used, instead of a flat out ban?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202406/402142) (and its answer).

Comment: You commented, @BrianTang, on this post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734645/how-do-i-do-that; posting links that users must click on in order to decipher the question(s), is risky for users, not knowing the source or origin of the links.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We already had users posting pornographic pictures, or stuff like that. I think that's a good enough reason.

At the very least require someone to add something of possible value to the site before adding something very terrible.

Comment: I'm chagrined to realize I never thought of that.  I'm not really that innocent. :-)

Comment: I'm chagrined to realise that it was the first thing I thought of. I thought I was innocent. $\ \ddot\smile$